# Pandas: how to fill missing data with a mean value?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I read from a remote device some data every 5 seconds.

They are saved as:

```
 2018-01-01 00:00:00    2
 2018-01-01 00:00:05    3
 2018-01-01 00:00:10    3
 2018-01-01 00:00:15    2
 2018-01-01 00:00:20    3
 2018-01-01 00:00:25    4
 2018-01-01 00:00:30    3
 2018-01-01 00:00:35    2
 2018-01-01 00:00:40    4
 2018-01-01 00:00:45    5
 2018-01-01 00:00:50    3
 2018-01-01 00:00:55    3
```

Alas communication is not the best, and sometimes communication is not working.

In that case the remote device will provide the **cumulative value** of the data as soon as possible.

The previous data could be saved as:

```
 2018-01-01 00:00:00     2
 2018-01-01 00:00:05     3
 2018-01-01 00:00:10     3
 .......... 00:00:15  missing...
 .......... 00:00:20  missing...
 .......... 00:00:25  missing...
 2018-01-01 00:00:30    12      <--- sum of the last 4 readings 
 2018-01-01 00:00:35     2
 .......... 00:00:40  missing...
 .......... 00:00:45  missing...
 2018-01-01 00:00:50    15      <--- sum of the last 3 readings
 2018-01-01 00:00:55     3
```

I need to fill all missing rows and remove the *peaks* in the original data with the **mean value** calculated on the *peak*.

Resampling is easy:

```
 2018-01-01 00:00:00      2
 2018-01-01 00:00:05      3
 2018-01-01 00:00:10      3
 2018-01-01 00:00:15    NaN
 2018-01-01 00:00:20    NaN
 2018-01-01 00:00:25    NaN
 2018-01-01 00:00:30     12
 2018-01-01 00:00:35      2
 2018-01-01 00:00:40    NaN
 2018-01-01 00:00:45    NaN
 2018-01-01 00:00:50     15
 2018-01-01 00:00:55      3
```

but **how to fill NaN and remove the peaks?**

I checked the various methods for `asfreq` and `resample` but none of them (`bfill`, `ffill`) is useful in this case.

The final result should be:

```
 2018-01-01 00:00:00      2
 2018-01-01 00:00:05      3
 2018-01-01 00:00:10      3
 2018-01-01 00:00:15      3 <--- NaN filled with mean = peak 12/4 rows
 2018-01-01 00:00:20      3 <--- NaN filled with mean
 2018-01-01 00:00:25      3 <--- NaN filled with mean
 2018-01-01 00:00:30      3 <--- peak changed
 2018-01-01 00:00:35      2
 2018-01-01 00:00:40      5  <--- NaN filled with mean = peak 15/3 rows
 2018-01-01 00:00:45      5  <--- NaN filled with mean
 2018-01-01 00:00:50      5  <--- peak changed
 2018-01-01 00:00:55      3
```

Dataframes I used for testing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

time = pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', freq='5s', periods=12)
read_data = pd.Series([2, 3, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 12, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 15, 3], index=time).dropna()

read_data.asfreq("5s")
```

Comment: I have a fundamental but not really quick solution: generate a full series of datetime, merge the full datetime column with your data, then you know which datetimes were missing. Then use ````if else```` to and ````flag```` to decide when should you get the mean. Achieve this using ````for loops````.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by **segmenting (*grouping*)** the missing values together with its corresponding peak value (after resampling) into a single group, backfill and then calculate mean of each group:

```
>>> read_data = read_data.to_frame(name='val').assign(idx=range(len(read_data)))
>>> read_data = read_data.asfreq('5s').bfill()
>>> read_data = read_data/read_data.groupby('idx').transform(len)
>>> read_data.drop('idx', axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> read_data.val
2021-01-01 00:00:00    2.0
2021-01-01 00:00:05    3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:10    3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:15    3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:20    3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:25    3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:30    3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:35    2.0
2021-01-01 00:00:40    5.0
2021-01-01 00:00:45    5.0
2021-01-01 00:00:50    5.0
2021-01-01 00:00:55    3.0
Freq: 5S, Name: val, dtype: float64
```

##### Explanation:

First convert your original series to dataframe and introduce another column ***idx*** which will uniquely identify each row as single groups:

```
>>> read_data = read_data.to_frame(name='val').assign(idx=range(len(read_data)))
>>> read_data
                      val  idx
2021-01-01 00:00:00   2.0    0
2021-01-01 00:00:05   3.0    1
2021-01-01 00:00:10   3.0    2
2021-01-01 00:00:30  12.0    3
2021-01-01 00:00:35   2.0    4
2021-01-01 00:00:50  15.0    5
2021-01-01 00:00:55   3.0    6
```

Resample to insert missing values, and then back-fill the missing values with peak values:

```
>>> read_data = read_data.asfreq('5s').bfill()
>>> read_data
                      val  idx
2021-01-01 00:00:00   2.0  0.0
2021-01-01 00:00:05   3.0  1.0
2021-01-01 00:00:10   3.0  2.0
2021-01-01 00:00:15  12.0  3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:20  12.0  3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:25  12.0  3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:30  12.0  3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:35   2.0  4.0
2021-01-01 00:00:40  15.0  5.0
2021-01-01 00:00:45  15.0  5.0
2021-01-01 00:00:50  15.0  5.0
2021-01-01 00:00:55   3.0  6.0
```

As you see now, the backfilled values are in same group as their peak (have same **idx**).

So `groupby` **`idx`** and just divide the the values by length of each group. Remove the ***idx*** column:

```
>>> read_data = read_data/read_data.groupby('idx').transform(len)
>>> read_data.drop('idx', axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> read_data
                     val
2021-01-01 00:00:00  2.0
2021-01-01 00:00:05  3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:10  3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:15  3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:20  3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:25  3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:30  3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:35  2.0
2021-01-01 00:00:40  5.0
2021-01-01 00:00:45  5.0
2021-01-01 00:00:50  5.0
2021-01-01 00:00:55  3.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Very well explained.

Comment: Glad to help `:)`

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
m = (read_data.isna() | read_data.shift(fill_value= 0).isna()).astype(int)
read_data = read_data.bfill() / m.groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()).transform('count').where(m.eq(1), 1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
2021-01-01 00:00:00    2.0
2021-01-01 00:00:05    3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:10    3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:15    3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:20    3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:25    3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:30    3.0
2021-01-01 00:00:35    2.0
2021-01-01 00:00:40    5.0
2021-01-01 00:00:45    5.0
2021-01-01 00:00:50    5.0
2021-01-01 00:00:55    3.0
Freq: 5S, dtype: float64
```

Complete Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

time = pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', freq='5s', periods=12)
read_data = pd.Series([2, 3, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 12, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 15, 3], index=time).dropna()

read_data = read_data.asfreq("5s")

m = (read_data.isna() | read_data.shift(fill_value= 0).isna()).astype(int)
read_data = read_data.bfill() / m.groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()).transform('count').where(m.eq(1), 1)
```

Comment: I thought your solution is perfect, alas `shift` brings in a little problem: if the groups of NaN are separated by a single value, the algorithm doesn't work. 

Try to change `periods=11` in `date_range` and remove the `2` after the `12` in the original dataframe to see what I mean.